# Question for three days at gettysburg

Tags: play-time

I don't have the rule book for the game Three days at Gettybusrg GMT. Could someone explain briefly how the mechanics works?

Such as, how many hexes can infantry/cavalry/artillery move per turn. How long is a turn and how long does it take for Renyolds (for example) to march north towards Gettysburg to support Bufford? Lastly, how far range do artillery or muskets fire?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rulebook and errata are [available](https://www.gmtgames.com/p-152-three-days-of-gettysburg.aspx) on GMTs website.